# Can phonons experience a photoelectric-like effect?

Tags: crystals, photoelectric-effect, lattice-model, phonons

In a crystal lattice, could phonons experience some form of the photoelectric effect?

Comment: What do you mean by "some form of the photoelectric effect"?